# docker-compose doesn't see docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

If you launch docker-run by yourself it works, if you do this with docker-compose it doesn't

```
roman@debian ~/D/O/devops> docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
ca4f61b1923c: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:083de497cff944f969d8499ab94f07134c50bcf5e6b9559b27182d3fa80ce3f7
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
 1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
 2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
    (amd64)
 3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
    executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
 4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
    to your terminal.

To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
 $ docker run -it ubuntu bash

Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
 https://cloud.docker.com/

For more examples and ideas, visit:
 https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/

roman@debian ~/D/O/devops> docker-compose build app
Building app
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run `docker-machine start default`.
roman@debian ~/D/O/devops>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's solved, previously been installing compose from repository, now installed through pip and it's working